# What is vetoing in the context of experimental particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, terminology, large-hadron-collider

I saw in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.04762) by the CMS Collaboration that two of the selection requirements defining the signal regions are the requirements on $b$ jet veto and $\tau_h$ veto. What is, in this context, a veto and what does it mean to require an event to have it to be included in the signal region?

Answer (score 1):

A simple example is as follows. Suppose you have a spectrometer (a detector that sits at a fixed angle, and has a dipole magnet to select momentum via $B/q$ and the bending radius of your spectrometer), and you're looking at:

$$ p(e, \pi^-)X $$

The data acquisition trigger is going to  have logical true pulses based on tracking chambers and perhaps scintillation paddles. You AND those together (with proper delay for time-of-flight) and record the event.

But...you are swamped with background from:

$$ p(e, e')X $$

so you get the gas Cherenkov detector, for which electrons at momentum $B/|e|$ radiate, and pions don't.

The Cherenkov detector output is converted to a logical signal, which then become the veto. If it's TRUE, it's not your signal, and it's sent to a logical gate that only emits TRUE if the Cherenkov is FALSE.

That was a hardware veto: using fast electric signals...typically 20 ns long pulses (though it can be tuned, depending)

Of course, it can get much more complicated in large detector with complicated background, with staged triggers in hardware, firmware and levels of software.

So a veto is any signal that says "don't trigger the read-out on this event".

Comment: So, when it says in the paper that I mentioned in the question that a $b$ jet veto is required for an event to be in the signal region, it means that events for which a $b$ jet is detected are not included in the signal region. Is this correct?